# Does it make sense do distribute n tasks over n+1 cores when parallel computing? R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I just started computing in Parallel in R to optimise my code, and although I understand the basic concept, I have a seemingly simple question that I haven't found the answer to.

If I have a foreach loop of **n** iterations and **m>n** cores available on my computer, would it speed up my code even more if I dedicate **n+1** or more cores to this computation, as opposed to allocating **n** cores?

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(m) #using m cores
registerDoParallel(cl)

object <– foreach(i = 1:n, ...) %dopar% {

[...]
} 

stopCluster(cl)
```

I think no, but it all comes down to how foreach distributes work to the cores. Is it one iteration per core at a time or is the work subdivided even further?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The others will be idle.

E.g. run this with a system monitor open:

```
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(4))

object <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% {

  start <- proc.time()[3]
  while (proc.time()[3] - start < 10) NULL
} 

stopCluster(cl)
```